# Mongoose - remote database connect failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to my mongo database in my remote server:

```
$ mongo xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017
```

But I get this error:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10 connecting to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017/test
>   2016-11-07T05:18:39.140+0000 warning: Failed to connect to
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
>   2016-11-07T05:18:39.142+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx), connection attempt failed at
>   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148 exception: connect failed

Any ideas why?

I even have tried to connect it with an username and password but it still fails to connect...

Comment: In which environment you're trying to run your mongod?

Comment: it will show startup warnings but working fine, for example i can able to query my dbs and collections.

Comment: @DavidR wut do u mean by `environment`? I'm on linux ubuntu.

Comment: I mean the Operating System

Comment: Can you show mongo conf `cat /etc/mongod.conf` there must be a line with `bind_ip 127.0.0.1,xx.xx.xx.xx` where xx.xx.xx.xx is your public IP

Comment: @Molda where should i run this `cat /etc/mongod.conf` for - my localhost or the remote server? When I run it for my localhost, i get this error: `cat: /etc/mongod.conf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Server of course, that's where you have mongodb installed right?

Comment: @Molda yes i have mongodb  installed in the remote server.

Comment: @Molda I get the same error even if I run that line in my remote server: `cat: /etc/mongod.conf: No such file or directory`. The remote server is on Arch Linux btw.

Comment: @teelou Well i'm not familiar with arch linux so can't help you with locating the file. Try `cat /etc/mongodb.conf` or try to find where is mongo conf file in your system, or even look into /etc/ directory if there's any file simillar to mongod.conf

Answer (score 1):

Run this following command :

```
sudo service mongodb stop
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod restart
mongo
```